# Laravel Model 1-n Instanciation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I was wondering how to make it right. Let's say we have 2 models:

- Object1
- Object2

The relationship between these two is 1-n:

- Object1 hasMany Object2
- Object2 belongsTo Object1

Note that in the DB we have followed the default attributes names (object1_id, ...)

When I want to instantiate:

```
$object1 = new Object1;
$object2_1 = new Object2;
$object2_2 = new Object2;
```

How to associate these two Object2 to Object1 before saving Object1 to the DB? Is there a way to do it without saving before Object1 to the DB and then use the ID of Object1 to attach these 2 Object2?

Something like:

```
$object1->add?($object2_1);
$object1->add?($object2_2);
$object1->save();
```

Knowing that we want that on the save() it will add to the DB the corresponding Object2's aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the right relation is:

- Object1 hasMany Object2
- Object2 BelongsTo Object1

then, you can do something like that:

```
$object1 = Object1::create([]);
$object2_1 = new App\Object2([]);
$object2_2 = new App\Object2([]);
```

then attach to **$object1** like this:

```
$object1->objects2()->saveMany([$object2_1, $object2_2]);
```